# Using CXXI to wrap C++ libraries

Tags: c#, c++, interop

My company is looking into CXXI for creating C# bindings to C++ libraries which will be used in Linux Mono. The main reason is the ease of use and simple looking bindings code. The main problem with CXXI is that its not finished, has no documentation, does not even compile in Ubuntu 12.04 and after making it compile, the tests and examples supplied don't even run.......

I know using Swig or creating the bindings manually is probably better than using CXXI at this point. I am just wondering if anyone has experience in using CXXI and can share their knowledge before I discard CXXI and move on.

Comment: I don't have any answers for you as I'm also looking into getting some c++ libraries working for me in c# land. I'm new in this area, thanks for raising the question. CHEERS

Answer (score 1):

I've seen C# communicating with native libraries on several platforms(iOS,Android) through SWIG, IMHO I think that this is the easiest path